# Как выложить код html в рамке на сайте?

Tags: html

Как выложить код html в рамке на сайте, что бы другие смогли его скопировать. Пример тут - синяя рамка.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Заменить скобки тегов на HTML-сущности:
    < на &lt;
    > на &gt;
    " на &quot;
    & на &amp;

И можно ещё на тег xmp посмотреть, [вот здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/html/xmp)

Ну, а рамку сделать - в стиле тега можно.

Answer (score 0):

Есть тега на панели више (101)
Или 4 пробела с начала строки

Answer (score 0):

помещаешь код в тег [`<pre>`](http://htmlbook.ru/html/pre) или даешь свойство [white-space](http://htmlbook.ru/css/white-space) к тегу + заворачиваешь в div или table и задаешь фон.